# How to replace String with different slashes?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I need to rename some paths in database.
I rename folder:

```
String mainFolder= "D:\test\1\data"; //folder renamed from fd
```

Then i need to rename all files and directories inside that folder:

```
    String file1="D:\test\1\fd\dr.jpg";
    String folder1="D:\test\1\fd\fd"; // in this case last fd needs to be renamed
    String folder2="src/fd/fd/"; //fake path also needs to be renamed
```

What is the best and fastest way to rename that strings?
My thoughts about "`/`":

```
        String folder2= "src/da/da";
        String[] splittedFakePath = folder2.split("/");
        splittedFakePath[splittedFakePath.length - 2] = "data";

        StringBuffer newFakePath = new StringBuffer();
        for (String str : splittedFakePath) {
            newFakePath.append(str).append("/");
        }
```

String after rename: `src/data/da/`
But when im trying split by "`\`":

```
Arrays.toString(Pattern.compile(File.separator).split(folder1));
```

I receive:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^
```

Comment: Did you remember to escape the backslash (`"\\\\"`)?

Comment: Backslash is a special character in regexes. You need to double it or use `Pattern.compile(File.separator,Pattern.LITERAL)`.

Comment: ``\`` is special in String literal but also in regular expression engine which `split` is using so you need to escape it twice: once in regex ``\\`` and second time in String `"\\\\"`.

Comment: It actually works with "\\\\"

Answer (score 0):

Look into java's `String` `replace(...)` method.

It is wonderful for string replacement, much better than attempting a regex.

Keep in mind that real directory handling has a few special cases, which don't lend themselves well to direct string manipulation.  For example '//' often gets compacted to '/' in Unix like systems, and if you care about proper directory corner-cases, then use the Java `Path` class

Comment: When i get a path of the file i receive string with "\" . Is it necessary to replace "\" with "/" before save them to database?

Comment: @RuslanLomov Remember that in Java, the character '\' is an escape indicator, for example '\n' is a newline, '\t' is a tab.  To get a single character you need to escape the slash, like so '\\'.  Also, I don't know what your database's requirements are, but those requirements are more important than my opinion.